# WordPress Admin Nav Showing in Frontend

Tags: wordpress

Anyone know how to remove the admin navigation links from the frontend? I've built a custom theme and when I am logged in to WordPress, WordPress is appending the admin nav bar somewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The admin bar?
Go to Users > Your Profile > Show Admin Bar. Here you can disable it from your theme. If you want to completely disable (remove) it, use one of various plugins, [like this](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-admin-bar-removal/).

Comment: Perfect! I wasn't aware of the admin bar settings in each individual user account. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Or you can remove it by default in functions.php.

```
/* Disable the Admin Bar. */
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );

<?php function yoast_hide_admin_bar_settings() { ?>
<style type="text/css">
    .show-admin-bar {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<?php }

function yoast_disable_admin_bar() {
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-profile.php',
     'yoast_hide_admin_bar_settings' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'yoast_disable_admin_bar' , 9 );
```

Thanks to Yoast (http://yoast.com/disable-wp-admin-bar/)

Answer (score 0):

Just this alone in the functions.php works for me.

```
// Remove Admin Bar Front End
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

Answer (score 0):

For wordpress 3.4.2, none of these workarounds should work. I have sorted out a very simple trick to hide the admin bar!

Just after you call the wp_head(), place this style declaration:

```
<style>
    html { margin-top: 0px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 0px !important; }
</style>
```

It involves no modification to the functions or whatever. Just plain old css!! 
I hope it solves the Googler's problem in near future :-)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your `functions.php`:

```
/* Disable WordPress Admin Bar for all users but admins. */
if(!current_user_can("manage_options")){
     show_admin_bar(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by plugin, link below:

> http://wordpress.org/plugins/global-admin-bar-hide-or-remove/